# Neural network classifies heavily towards few particular classes

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, sentiment-analysis

I am performing sentiment analysis on a dataset of Movie Reviews. The neural network is a single-hidden layer NN, made from scratch in Python. The classifier is expected to assign one of five classes(0 to 4) to each review phrase. however, upon training, the confusion matrix for the dev set gives the following results:

[image]

This means that the classifier is heavily biased towards class 0 and class 4. What could be the possible reasons?
The classifier earlier predicted only class 2 always because the dataset was skewed (~ 50% of the data was from class 2). Hence I chose a subset of the dataset containing an equal number of examples from all 5 classes. I still don't understand the output and low accuracy.
The link to my notebook can be found [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1tTZzaRHpm9NTnRQ8WlCQHOa6xGFzP-WE?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

first of all your model is linear, with only 1 layer. so its simple model which might not produce good results, try increasing number of layers.

you training cost is also very high, you have to train for more epochs until you get good training cost. which also affect your validation cost which is twice the training cost.

it is sign of over fitting.